# Prime beginning by 2

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analysis

How to deal with that type of question ? 
Are there infinite prime numbers beginning by 2? 
I know that there infinite prime ending by 1,3,7 and 9 by Dirichlet’s prime number theorem.

I’am only interested by the first term in special case 2. Not for a generalization. I think that this specific case provide a simpler proof than the generalization.

Comment: I guess so, and I think you can prove this by estimates on prime gaps/densities.

Comment: The distribution of first digits tends to uniformity: https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3302

Comment: @Jam thanks you

Comment: I disagree with your decision to close this one as a duplicate. This problem is MUCH simpler and does not need a complex solution of a more complex problem. The starting sequence in this case is a single digit.